# Autocomplete not working in only one ViewController

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, code-completion

I am working on a project which has a mix of Objective C and Swift. It has a relatively long number of ViewControllers and suddenly autocomplete stopped working in one of them.

I tried all the solutions mentioned from other posts

1) Deleted derived data and restarted
2) Cleaned (and also Cleaned Build folder)
3) Tried Restarting Mac
4) Removed .m file from Build phases and reattached it, nothing worked.

[image]

Not working here

But is working fine in any other ViewCo[image]ntroller

[image]

Comment: Did you wait for Xcode completed the indexing?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. And also I am able to run the simulator and on the device without any issues (I assume build is only possible after indexing is done, so).

Comment: On Xcode 9, indexing and building process can work parallel. So if you can build success, it does not mean the indexing is completed.

Comment: I just allowed it to index and tried, still no luck. Can I try something else for it to work ?

Comment: Does it work on another machine? If yes, you can delete that source, and download again (with git, I suppose)

Comment: I was also facing the same issue but after restarting Xcode several times it was resolved.After some months i again faced same issue but this time restarting Xcode didn't helped.So i made a new class and copied all code to this new file and deleted the original one and guess what??  The issue was resolved :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I had to go back to my previous commit and then do some pod updates, restarts and suddenly it started working again. I am not 100% sure what was the reason it stopped working and what was reason it again started working, but I think it was some kind off bug, multiple restarts + setting up the code again did it for me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ViewController from project and add it again, It will solve your problem. It happens some time in Xcode. It's Xcode's problem. It is independent of language you are using.